# How to forward Auth0's ID token to GraphQL Code Generator?

Tags: javascript, graphql, next.js, auth0, graphql-codegen

I am using GraphQL Code Generator with [React Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/), this is my `codegen.yml`:

```yaml
overwrite: true

schema: http://localhost:4000/graphql

generates:
  src/lib/__generated__/graphql.ts:
    documents:
      - "**/graphql/**/*.graphql"
      - "!mysqldata/**"
    plugins:
      - add:
          content: &comment "/* DO NOT EDIT! this file was generated by graphql-codegen */\n/* eslint-disable */"
      - add:
          placement: append
          content: "export { fetcher }"
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-react-query
    config:
      fetcher:
        endpoint: "`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/graphql`"
        fetchParams:
          credentials: include
          headers:
            Content-Type: application/json
```

This generates the following fetcher:

```js
function fetcher<TData, TVariables>(query: string, variables?: TVariables) {
  return async (): Promise<TData> => {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/graphql` as string, {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {"Content-Type":"application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
    });
    
    const json = await res.json();

    if (json.errors) {
      const { message } = json.errors[0];

      throw new Error(message);
    }

    return json.data;
  }
}
```

`NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL` refers to an external GraphQL API.
In my Next.js application I tried to make use of [nextjs-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0) and [auth0-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/auth0-react).

`nextjs-auth0` allows me to access Auth0's ID token from Next.js API routes:

```js
export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const session = getSession(req, res)
  const idToken = session?.idToken
```

while `auth0-react` allows me to get the token client side:

```js
const claims = await auth0.getIdTokenClaims();
const idToken = claims.__raw;
```

The problem is that because of these abstractions, I cannot figure out a way to include this token in requests to my GraphQL endpoint like:

```js
headers: {
  authorization: `Bearer ${session?.idToken}`,
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I posted a [feature request](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/issues/504) to include the ID token inside a cookie, I figured the "appSession" cookie that's set by `nextjs-auth0` is an encrypted token which includes the ID token, I implemented custom server logic using the `nextjs-auth0` source code as reference:

```js
type DecodedToken = Record<"idToken" | "token_type", string>

const API_BASE_URL = "https://example.com"
const BYTE_LENGTH = 32
const ENCRYPTION_INFO = "JWE CEK"
const HASH = "SHA-256"
const alg = "dir"
const enc = "A256GCM"

/**
 * Derives appropriate sized keys from provided secret random string/passphrase using
 * HKDF (HMAC-based Extract-and-Expand Key Derivation Function) defined in RFC 8569
 * @see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5869
 */
function deriveKey(secret: string) {
  return hkdf(secret, BYTE_LENGTH, { info: ENCRYPTION_INFO, hash: HASH })
}

export const meQueryField = queryField("me", {
  type: "User",
  async resolve(_, __, ctx) {
    const jwe = ctx.request.cookies["appSession"]

    if (!jwe) {
      return null
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
    const octKey = JWK.asKey(deriveKey(process.env["AUTH0_SECRET"]!))

    const { cleartext } = JWE.decrypt(jwe, octKey, {
      complete: true,
      contentEncryptionAlgorithms: [alg],
      keyManagementAlgorithms: [enc],
    })

    const { idToken, token_type: tokenType } = JSON.parse(
      cleartext.toString()
    ) as DecodedToken

    const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/users/me`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `${tokenType} ${idToken}`,
      },
    })

    const user = (await response.json()) as Response

    return {
      id: user.data.id,
      ...
    }
  },
})
```

It's not pretty but it works. `AUTH0_SECRET` is the same secret that's used to encrypt the token in `nextjs-auth0`

Comment: Please consider marking your answer as the solution (once that is possible).